# How to read the xml file in netbeans

Tags: java

I am using net beans IDE for development and  keeping all my xml files under the folder XML(created under Web Pages folder) ..

I am using the following code to read the xml file .

```
File file = new File("XML/TableNamesAndColumnNames.xml");
```

but it is giving file not found exception ..

Can any one suggest how to read the file

Thanks in Advance

Raj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the path you are specifying is not the correct one. Find out what you application's `working directory` is. Run this:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

And then adjust from there accordingly.

Comment: Hi Geo, I am not a registered user to vote ... I am trying to register since 2 weeks but I cant.. Please suggest me a way to register..